# NSPredicate to get a single attribute back from multiple objects in an array

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, nspredicate

This seems like it would be fairly simple to do, but I can't find anything referencing this specifically.

Say I have an array of `Post` objects that each have an `objectId`. How can I create an array of only the `objectId`'s?

something like:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"objectId ALL"]; // I just want all the objectIds...
NSArray *results = [[self.objects filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate] mutableCopy];
```

or

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"objectId matches {anything}"];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSPredicate` cannot return anything other than `BOOL`, so it cannot return `objectId`. Moreover, `filteredArrayUsingPredicate:` can change the number of items in your array, but it will keep the objects themselves unchanged.

If you want to start with one object and produce another object, you need `NSExpression`. It can transform your object into something else - for example, by projecting one of its attributes. However, Cocoa offers no built-in way of *applying* `NSExpression` to an `NSArray` in a way similar to `filteredArrayUsingPredicate:`, so `NSExpression` would not help here.

You can solve this by using a little trick, though:

```
NSString *key = NSStringFromSelector(@selector(objectId));
NSMutableArray *allIds= [[array valueForKey:key] mutableCopy];
```

If you use this in production code, it is a good idea to document it heavily by a few lines of comments. Otherwise, the readers of your code (including you in about six months or so) are virtually guaranteed to get confused.

Comment: ok, but just clarify. what's the difference between what you're suggesting and simply just: `NSMutableArray *allIds= [[array valueForKey:@"objectId"] mutableCopy];`

Comment: @gadu If you decide to rename `objectId` to, say, `objectKey` in your class, but forget to rename it in the code that gets all ids, the compiler is going to catch it when you use `@selector`, and produce an error. If you use the plain string `@"objectId"`, the code would compile, but fail at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so it turns out this is not a task for NSPredicate, which is why I couldn't find out how to do it using that. Instead I can do this pretty easily with key-value coding (KVC).

If you want to simply retrieve something and not filter then:

```
NSArray *results = [self.objects valueForKey:@"objectId"];
```